# how can i set -ORBInitialRef without using cmd?

Tags: java, corba

i cleaned and built my program in net beans. i want to use jar file but i dont know how can i set -ORBInitialRef ?

```
java RunServer -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:777/NameService
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it some kind of a java VM argument (or System property) specified like

```
java RunServer -DORBInitRef <value>
```

because simply passing the values to the java command is passing arguments to the RunServer program.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter whether it's a command line argument, or a JVM system property that's set, as long as it gets passed into the `ORB.init()` function.  The CORBA Orb init() function is smart enough to parse the arguments and pass the arguments that begin with `-ORB` along during ORB creation.

Take a look at some java ORB initialisation examples here:  http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/MP/orb/tutorial/orbInit.html